# Convert delimited file to fixed width in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

Using tools available to bash, how do I convert delimited data

```
foo|bbbaaarrr|bazz
```

to fixed width data

```
foo      bbbaaarrrbazz     EOL
```

I tried using column as the documentation implied I could define the column width, didn't work.
I'm sure this is trivial using sed or awk, but I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: Show us some sample input and desired output.

Comment: 1) Are the columns all the same width? 2) What is your expectation if a value exceeds the column width?

Comment: The input columns will be different widths, I'm forcing the output to be the same width.  My expectation is that it should die spectacularly, as the input data is strictly defined (which is why I have no clue as to why they insist on this format to exchange this data)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
column -t -s '|' input_file_here
```

It will convert the input file to table format.  The input record separator is specified by `-s`.  If you want something other than space padding in the fields, use `-o` to set the output separator.  The output separator defaults to two spaces, so there will be two spaces between each column in the output.

**Example:**

```
$ cat input
hello|world|testing
a|b|c
another|test|line

$ column -t -s '|' input
hello    world  testing
a        b      c
another  test   line
```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html

---

Edit:

If you need each field to be a fixed length, you can use `awk` for that.  You'll need to set the input delimiter for your file, but something like this should work:

```
$ awk -F '|' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { printf("%-10s", $i); } print ""; }' input
hello     world     testing
a         b         c
another   test      line
```

Just change the field width specified in the `printf` statement.

Comment: That's what I thought, using -c to define the column width.  Didn't work, other man pages imply that -c defines number of columns.  I think column is just a type of pretifier.  In your example, the column widths are defined by the width of the longest parameter.

Comment: @RickDeBay - See edit.  If you need fields truncated to fitting, you'll also need to use `substr($i, 1, your_len_here)` instead of just `$i`.

Comment: One minor improvement (assuming truncation is desired): to pass the width as a parameter: `awk -F '|' -v w=9 '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%-*s", w, substr($i,1,w); print ""}' file`

Comment: Perfect.  I prepended a test to exclude line one as well.  No idea why people feel it's required to start with a list of column names.